# "Safe handle has been closed" error for Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceClient.PullAsync

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database

I am suddenly getting the following error since yesterday:

```
"Safe handle has been closed" error for Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceClient.PullAsync
```

I cannot think what has changed. The error only happens for calls against `TableController` that do not need authorization. When I log in, using Azure AD B2C, the calls against the rest of the `Tablecontrollers` go fine.

The following stack trace is unhelpful (at least to me):

```
"   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.DangerousAddRef(Boolean& success)\r\n   
at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.SafeHandleAddRef(SafeHandle pHandle, Boolean& success)\r\n   
at SQLitePCL.SQLite3Provider_e_sqlite3.NativeMethods.sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqlite3 db, Byte* pSql, Int32 nBytes, IntPtr& stmt, Byte*& ptrRemain)\r\n   
at SQLitePCL.SQLite3Provider_e_sqlite3.SQLitePCL.ISQLite3Provider.sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqlite3 db, utf8z sql, IntPtr& stm, utf8z& tail)\r\n   
at SQLitePCL.raw.sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqlite3 db, utf8z sql, sqlite3_stmt& stmt)\r\n   
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.SQLiteStore.MobileServiceSQLiteStore.ExecuteQueryInternal(TableDefinition table, String sql, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.SQLiteStore.MobileServiceSQLiteStore.ExecuteQueryInternal(String tableName, String sql, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.SQLiteStore.MobileServiceSQLiteStore.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<LookupAsync>b__0(Task t)\r\n   
at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromTask`1.InnerInvoke()\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__278_1(Object obj)\r\n   
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location ---\r\n   
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)\r\n   
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)\r\n
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---\r\n   
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Sync.MobileServiceSyncSettingsManager.<GetSettingAsync>d__12.MoveNext()\r\n   
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Sync.MobileServiceSyncSettingsManager.<GetDeltaTokenAsync>d__8.MoveNext()\r\n   
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Sync.IncrementalPullStrategy.<InitializeAsync>d__13.MoveNext()\r\n   
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Sync.PullAction.<CreatePullStrategy>d__20.MoveNext()\r\n   
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Sync.PullAction.<ProcessTableAsync>d__14.MoveNext()\r\n   
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Sync.TableAction.<ExecuteAsync>d__29.MoveNext()\r\n   
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Sync.MobileServiceSyncContext.<ExecuteSyncAction>d__35.MoveNext()\r\n   
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Sync.MobileServiceSyncContext.<PullAsync>d__31.MoveNext()\r\n   
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   
at Valufy.Data.OffLineSync.<SyncNonAuthAsync>d__109.MoveNext() in C:\\Users\\sreesun\\OneDrive\\Projects\\Valufy21\\Valufy\\Valufy\\Data\\OfflineSync.cs:line 1931"
```

Comment: The error message says that you are trying to access an object which is already disposed. Or you are disposing something which is still being used by a different thread. Please check your calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Wendy Zang for pointing me in the right direction. It turns out that the manifestation of this error was misleading (at least to me). The issue was caused by instantiating multiple static objects and disposing them in the wrong order. Essentially, it was exactly as Wendy said. I was accessing multiple copies of static objects in a haphazard order leading to this confusion. I cleaned up my code and refactored some of the calls.

A point of mystery to me is how it worked all along in debug UWP mode. When I was trying to test it out on the Android simulator, the problem came to fore.